# Dumping JSON data straight into a text file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Currently, I can't get the data being received from my other client software to write into a file that will append as well as add a space after each dump. I Tried quite a few different approaches but I'm left with this now and I'm a bit stumped.

At the moment I can no longer get a file to write and I'm not sure what I've done to destroy that part of my code.

```
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    if data:
        with open("data.txt", 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I am expecting a file will appear that will not be overwritten each time I receive new data, allowing me to develop my search and table features of my application.

Comment: You open the file with 'w', writing, which always starts a new file. Open it with 'a' for appending.

Comment: Or just open the file outside of the while loop, keep it open the whole time, close it when you're done.

Comment: Also note that if you're dumping multiple JSON objects into a single file like that, a JSON parser that follows the standard (e.g. Python) will not be able to read it.

Comment: If you are receiving JSON data, you don't need to encode it again with `json.dump`; just write `data` directly to the file.

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing for each block:

1. Decode the block as UTF
2. Open a file, truncating the previous contents (`'w'` mode)
3. Re-encode the data
4. Dump it to the file

Why this is a bad way to do it:

1. Your blocks are not necessarily going to respect UTF code point boundaries. You need to accumulate all the data before you decode.
2. Not only are you tuncating theexisting  file by using `'w'` instead of `'a'` mode, but opening and closing a file over and over is very inefficient and generally a bad idea.
3. You are not going to get the same result if the original block was off a UTF boundary. Worst case, your whole dataset will be trash.
4. You have no way of ending the stream. You probably want to close the file eventually and decode it.

How you should do it:

1. Open an output file (in binary mode)
2. Loop until the stream ends
3. Dump all your raw binary packets to a file
4. Close the file
5. Decode the file when you read it

Sample code:

```
with open('data.txt', 'wb') as file:
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        file.write(data)
```

If the binary stream contains UTF-8 encoded JSON data, that's what you will get in your file.